# Can't find python lib .so and init spacy in R Studio?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, python-2.7, nlp

I am trying to do the following:

```
reticulate::use_python(python = "/usr/bin/python3", required = TRUE)

py_discover_config():
python:         /usr/bin/python3
libpython:      [NOT FOUND]
pythonhome:     /usr:/usr
version:        3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55)  [GCC 8.2.0]
numpy:          /home/ssolun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.3

NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON

reticulate::py_config():
```

> Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : Python
>   shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.

```
cleanNLP::cnlp_init_spacy():
```

> Error: Python not available See reticulate::use_python() to set python
>   path, then retry

Please advise how to solve these errors?
I am trying to init spacy for NLP analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
sudo apt install git libpython3.7-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, this code works    `reticulate::use_python(python = "C:/Users/andrea.contardi/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.7", required = TRUE)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNURT.png)